# Not getting response from ICMP echo request, all routing tables seems correct

Tags: networking, router, routing, ping

The data network shown below is experiencing a communications failure between the
Network A and Network B.

[Data Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSLer.png)

Also, here you can see the routing tables of all the routers: [Routing Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eKyw.png)

It is confirmed that all the configuration of the interfaces in the Routers and VPCs is correct and all the WAN links are operational. I have used the PING command from PC-A to PC-D, checking that it is NOT being obtaining a response from the ICMP Echo Request messages that PC-A sends to PC-D and that PC-D must respond with an ICMP Echo Reply message.

So, I need to **Identify the name of the router where it is necessary to take action to solve this routing failure**.

And also **indicate which is the solution and write which is the line or lines of complete command that must be added in that Router in order to solve the routing problem**.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework/online assignment to me. **"indicate which is the solution and write which is the line or lines of complete command that must be added in that Router in order to solve the routing problem."** ~ lol this literally looks like you copy and pasted it out of a exam...

Comment: Router-C has no route for RED-D. Cisco exam?

Comment: It is a homework haha. thanks @BenjaminHastings I'm I little bit blind.